# What happens to a comment flag if that comment gets deleted by its author?

Tags: support, comment-flags

Imagine the following sequence of events:

- Some user posts a question or an answer.
- User A comments that post.
- User B flags the comment as, say, unfriendly or unkind, and doesn't retract that flag.
- User A deletes the comment.

What will be the status of the flag then? Will it be “helpful”, “declined”, or “disputed”? I suppose that it will not remain “pending” until it ages away.

Comment: I guess it gets reviewed the same as a flag on a deleted post.  I've raised flags on deleted posts before; they got marked as helpful/unhelpful depending on the severity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### It is marked helpful by the Community user

Comment flags on comments are marked as helpful when the comment is deleted, unless marked as declined by a moderator. Doesn't matter if the comment is self deleted, flag deleted or mod deleted.

For a specific case, I dug up an example of a comment being posted, flagged and then self-deleted (usernames simplified).

[image]

Comment: This is how it's *supposed* to work, but [there are edge cases where it's broken](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/a/3518) (mod-only link).